# +1/Like/Share button for web based mobile app

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, jquery-mobile, google-plus

I'm creating a web-based mobile application using jQuery Mobile.

I want to add "+1" and "Share" buttons (for Google+) and "Like" and "Share" buttons (for Facebook) to my application. but all of these buttons may use a popup window (e.g. for logging in).

Since my goal is creating a mobile web application, I shouldn't have any popup windows. So I can't use these default buttons.

Isn't there any way to have these four buttons **without any popup window**? (I don't know, maybe iframes, or an integrated system on our server, or something else...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all OAuth services.  So if you want to do something besides using typical javascript widgets, you will need to familiarize yourself with OAuth and make all of the respective browser redirections to the login pages yourself.

Comment: It would be nice if you add some examples, or tutorial links for this.

Comment: It is a pretty complex integration, that you would need to make with each service with which you would look to integrate.  You should simply refer to the developer documentation for each service for integration examples.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? (e.g. opening google sign in form in an iframe, or ...)

Comment: You could perhaps use iframes and such, but the problem remains that if you don't want to use some sort of existing code functionality, you will need to learn what that existing code does (i.e OAuth login) and implement it yourself.  You could try to reverse engineering the javascript code and override the actual window opening behavior, but my guess is you will find that these js snippets are minimized with short variable names and such and not very easy to sort through.  You can also look for individual javascript code made by other users that does what you want.

Comment: What do you think about this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/   isn't there such things for sharing on facebook & google+, and +1?

Comment: Notice that within that document it discussing having a user that is fb-authed.  That means they have already performed an OAtuh login to facebook.  That functionality is great an all but still requires an OAuth login. You really need to understand how OAuth works relative to these services before venturing down the road of trying to build your own functionality.